# [JAVA]How to print an array from another class into a GUI(using JFrame)?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm working on a code that contains multiple classes. I'm trying show an array that I've already created an another class, into a GUI or JTextArea. However, I keep getting an error. Let me note that this specific array was created to store data from a file.

Here's part of my code:

```
public class THEGUI{  
    SUB c= new SUB(); *//in which SUB is a class that contains my array*
    String[] word= c.three(*W*);*//three is a method in the class SUB

    *//the text area*
    JTextArea textAreaLeft = new JTextArea(5, 20);
       textAreaLeft.setEditable(false);
       JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textAreaLeft);
       frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
       frame.add(c.three(W))
```

---

**In class SUB(a completely different class/.java file):**

```
class SUB{
    public static String[] W;
}
```

---

Why am I getting an error when trying to pass the array W into my three method, when I declared it already in the W class? I can't seem to place the declared array into the GUI. The GUI TextArea is empty. If you need me to clarify, please ask.

Also, I apologize for the formatting. not sure how to fix that. new here :/

Comment: Why are you getting *what* error??

Comment: `String[] word= c.three(W);` <- `W` is undefined in this context

Comment: Yes. That's the exact error: W is undefined in this context. I declared it in the SUB class though.

Comment: And what relationship does `W` have with `THEGUI`?

Comment: `W` is an array I created to store the contents of a file. It's array that contains words. `THEGUI` is a GUI that I'm trying to create that displays the content of the array `W`. It's suppose to show `W` 's content in the GUI.

Comment: Where are you filling `W` (a very poor name for a variable by the way -- variable names should be descriptive and should begin with a lower-case letter) with data? Why is it static?

Comment: `W` is stored in the `SUB` class.`W` is an array(I called it W for words. Maybe I should've specified) In the `SUB` class,I used StringTokenizer to take the contents of a file and store in it the array. I don't have a specific reason as to why it's static. Should I change it?

Comment: I guess the error is simply because you're trying to access `W` as if it was a field of your `THEGUI` class - use `c.three(SUB.W)` instead. It's very bad practice to use public static fields like that, though. It would be much better to pass the array to the constructor of `THEGUI`

Comment: Yes, never make a field static for no reason at all. Otherwise you're completely throwing out all object-oriented benefits.

Comment: Thank you all. I apologize for not clarifying further in the beginning. I removed 'static' from in front of `W`. However, I forgot to mention that method `three()` only takes arrays. Should I try to make a constructor of `THEGUI` in the `SUB` class?

Comment: As stated in other comments : your `THEGUI` class has no `W` attribute. That is why `W` is reported as `undefined in this context`. Furthermore, the code you are pasting for `THEGUI` JTextArea should be inside a `method`. If you want that method to access the `W`attribute (question of @madprogrammer) of a SUB instance (your variable `c`), you should create an accessor to W in the SUB class (if W is supposed to be private to SUB), or declare W as a public member of SUB class. (see @ohlec answer)